# Is there a good interactive 3D graph library out there?

Tags: layout, 3d, graph, interactive

I'm looking for a library that will layout and display graphs (i.e. network diagrams, not charts) in 3D, with some interactivity like selecting and dragging nodes, rotating the display etc. I would like to do this in a web page so Javascript or Flash are preferable, I'd also consider Java.

Having looked myself I realise the options are very limited so I'm interested to hear of any such libraries regardless of language or interactivity, even if they don't run in a browser. 3D is essential though, there are other questions on this site convering 2D libraries.

Update: please, stop adding details of 2D graph libraries. As the question states, I'm only looking for 3D libraries and there are other questions covering 2D graphs.

Comment: I'm offering a bounty as I'm sure there must be more libraries out there. Do add any you know of, one per answer please to let the best rise to the top.

Comment: Since you're not looking for something complex and you don't need much performance, why not implement your own, using 2D canvas? 3D to 2D transformations involve some really simple math; "OpenGL Redbook" (freely downloadable) includes some great info on how GL works in the appendices. If you can implement matrix multiplication, and if you can draw in JS 2D canvas, you can do 3D. I say: If you want the wheel done right, do it yourself, especially if all you can find are wooden bricks. // Posting as comment since obviously this does not answer the (very specific) question about libraries.

Answer (score 4):

[Walrus](https://www.caida.org/catalog/software/walrus/)

Pros: great looking interactive 3D graph library, in Java.

Cons: not actively maintained, last update in 2003.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [caida.org](https://www.caida.org/tools/visualization/walrus/gallery1/ries-t2-thumb.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It's C++ & SDL/OpenGL, but you might find [Forg3D](http://kokki.uku.fi/bioinformatics/forg3d/) of interest (see also this [paper](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1752-0509/3/26)).
I have no experience with it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful:

> [Processing](http://www.proce55ing.net/) is an open source
>   programming language and environment
>   for people who want to program images,
>   animation, and interactions.

Comment: Er... although I'd consider an incomplete or feature-limited library, I'm looking for something *a little* higher level than that!

Comment: Have you seen what you can do with it? http://www.proce55ing.net/exhibition/works/001/index_link.html

Comment: Regardless, it is not a graph library as the question asks for.

Comment: It is, it is simply much more as well. A 3D scence graph is entirely built in, along with camera manipulation, object selection (albeit tricky without a hint or two). If you want something to look pretty then you'll find it hard to beat in the long run, albeit not as pretty straight out of the box.
What it doesn't do it hold your hand in the same way as some of the others, which is a real complaint (and a perfectly valid reason or you to discard it). But saying it isn't a graph library is pushing it.

Answer (score 1):

[WilmaScope](http://wilma.sourceforge.net/) is a Java 3D network editor.  Nice screenshots [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/screenshots.php?group_id=14725&ssid=892) and [here](http://wilma.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Starlight](http://starlight.pnl.gov/) is a powerful 3D visualization tool I used once, several years ago (2005?) for a project.  I remember it being quite powerful at the time.  Then I was not concerned with a web UI.  It is still actively maintained and has a separate non-government entity to handle commercial licensing.